# VB6 to C# interop: Cannot directly set a property of type 'object'

Tags: com, vb6, interop, object

Given the following C# class:

```
namespace ComTest
{
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    [Guid("A1D11BE5-40A1-4566-A1CA-418ABC76017C")]
    public interface IThing
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        void SetValue( object input );
        [DispId(2)]
        object Value {get; set;}
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Thing: IThing
    {
        internal object PValue;

        public void SetValue(object input)
        {
            PValue = input;
        }

        public object Value
        {
            get
            {
                return PValue;
            }
            set
            {
                PValue = (object)value;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Can anyone explain the following behaviour in VB6?

```
Dim oThing as Thing
Dim input as Variant, output as Variant
input = "Some text"
Set oThing = new Thing
oThing.SetValue(input)    ' works fine
output = oThing.Value     ' works fine
Set oThing.Value = input  ' fails with runtime error '424': Object required
```

[new]
I set the assembly to be COM-visible and checked the project properties box marked "Register for COM interop" (Build tab).

As you may guess, the example is a cut down minimal version of the actual class I am using.  I compared the generated TLB info for the actual class and the Thing class (below).
The lines marked ** are found in the Thing class but not the actual class (the actual coclass contains [default] dispinterface IThing), and this extra generated interface _Thing appears to change the behaviour in VBA, in two ways: (1) the properties will no longer AutoComplete, (2) the direct assignment to Value now works as the contributors have found.  Any thoughts?

```
// Generated .IDL file (by the OLE/COM Object Viewer)
// 
// typelib filename: ThingLib.tlb
[
  uuid(92093AA7-870E-498A-8B80-97545D221E24),
  version(1.0),
  helpstring("AAA Testing COM interop")
]
library ThingLib
{
    // TLib :     // TLib : mscorlib.dll : {BED7F4EA-1A96-11D2-8F08-00A0C9A6186D}
    importlib("mscorlib.tlb");
    // TLib : OLE Automation : {00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    // Forward declare all types defined in this typelib
    dispinterface IThing;
**  interface _Thing;

    [
      uuid(7FC255DD-F82F-4B39-8755-9680A97033B5),
      version(1.0),
        custom({0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9}, "ComTest.IThing")    

    ]
    dispinterface IThing {
        properties:
        methods:
            [id(0x00000001)]
            void SetValue([in] VARIANT input);
            [id(0x00000002), propget]
            VARIANT Value();
            [id(0x00000002), propputref]
            void Value([in] VARIANT rhs);
    };

    [
      uuid(D96FB9C7-A0AF-35D3-A0F6-A07A9ED47984),
      version(1.0),
        custom({0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9}, "ComTest.Thing")
    ]
    coclass Thing {
**      [default] interface _Thing;
        interface _Object;
        dispinterface IThing;
    };

**    [
**      odl,
**      uuid(C309BDD0-239F-38AA-A057-254F8E01BD4B),
**      hidden,
**      dual,
**      oleautomation,
**        custom({0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9}, "ComTest.Thing")    
**    ]
**    interface _Thing : IDispatch {
**    };
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your code to:

```
Dim oThing as Thing
Dim input as Variant, output as Variant
input = "Some text"
Set oThing = new Thing
oThing.SetValue(input)    ' works fine
output = oThing.Value     ' works fine
Set oThing.Value = input  ' Change this line
```

And everything should work.  (You have to Set objects in VB6, you are trying to
Let an object, which can only be done for atomic types).

Comment: You are right in that the code I gave works (when typo corrected) but the original class from which I copied it still does not work.  See my edited question for COM (TLB) information differences between the original and the cut down example - I can't figure out what caused the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy, I tried your code and it works fine (although I used Excel VBA since I do not have VB6 installed).  There is a typo in your code where

```
object Value (get; set;)
```

should be

```
object Value {get; set;}
```

but I doubt that it has anything to do with your error since it should give you a compile error.  Did you try the code exactly as you put it here?

Answer (score 0):

I also tried your COM interface implementation with a VB6 client without any problems (with the exception of the typo Jakob mentioned in the `Value` property).